# Splitting a column to normalized table

Tags: mysql, performance, normalization, query-performance

I have a de-normalized table as

**Original De-Normalized Table**

```
id  text
23  first,second|third,fourth,fifth|sixth
```

I want to normalize the database to create the following tables

**Table 1: (Split by "|")**

```
id  parent_id   value
1   23          first,second
2   23          third,fourth,fifth
3   23          sixth
```

and then,

**Table 2 (Split by ",")**

```
id  parent_id   value
1   1           first
2   1           second
3   2           third
4   2           fourth
5   2           fifth
6   3           sixth
```

The easiest and straightforward method is to use sub-query (`SELECT`), but my concern is the performance, as this process should be conducted for a very long table and regularly (new data coming).

Is there an efficient way to normalize this table with high speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a Stored Procedure solution to perform the following:

- Convert the txt field of t1 into an extended INSERT list delimiting by '|'
- Execute the extended INSERTs
- Convert the value field of t2 into an extended INSERT list delimiting by ','
- Execute the extended INSERTs

Here is the sample data

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS all_denorm;
CREATE DATABASE all_denorm;
USE all_denorm
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t3;
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    txt TEXT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO  t1 (id,txt) VALUES
(23,'first,second|third,fourth,fifth|sixth'),
(24,'seventh,eighth|ninth|tenth,eleven|twelfth'),
(25,'thirteenth|fourteenth|fifteenth|sixteen|seventeenth'),
(26,'eighteenth,nineteenth|twentieth');
CREATE TABLE t2
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT NOT NULL,
    VALUE VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE t3 LIKE t2;
```

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `all_denorm`.`process_denorm` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `all_denorm`.`process_denorm` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE given_id,current_id,last_id,processing INT;
    DECLARE delimiter_char CHAR(1);

    SET current_id = 0;
    SET processing = 1;
    SET delimiter_char = '|';
    WHILE processing = 1 DO
        SELECT MIN(id) INTO given_id FROM t1 WHERE id > current_id;
        IF ISNULL(given_id) THEN
            SET processing = 0;
        ELSE
            SET current_id = given_id;
            SELECT
                REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('(''',REPLACE(txt,delimiter_char,'''),('''),''')'),'(','(QQQ,'),'QQQ',FLOOR(given_id))
                INTO @insert_list FROM t1 WHERE id = given_id;
            SELECT CONCAT('insert into t2 (parent_id,value) values ',@insert_list) INTO @insert_SQL;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_SQL;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    SET current_id = 0;
    SET processing = 1;
    SET delimiter_char = ',';
    WHILE processing = 1 DO
        SELECT MIN(id) INTO given_id FROM t2 WHERE id > current_id;
        IF ISNULL(given_id) THEN
            SET processing = 0;
        ELSE
            SET current_id = given_id;
            SELECT
                REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('(''',REPLACE(value,delimiter_char,'''),('''),''')'),'(','(QQQ,'),'QQQ',FLOOR(given_id))
                INTO @insert_list FROM t2 WHERE id = given_id;
            SELECT CONCAT('insert into t3 (parent_id,value) values ',@insert_list) INTO @insert_SQL;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_SQL;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM t1;
    SELECT * FROM t2;
    SELECT * FROM t3;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here it is executed

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS all_denorm;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE all_denorm;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE all_denorm
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     txt TEXT
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO  t1 (id,txt) VALUES
    -> (23,'first,second|third,fourth,fifth|sixth'),
    -> (24,'seventh,eighth|ninth|tenth,eleven|twelfth'),
    -> (25,'thirteenth|fourteenth|fifteenth|sixteen|seventeenth'),
    -> (26,'eighteenth,nineteenth|twentieth');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE TABLE t2
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     parent_id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     VALUE VARCHAR(255),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t3 LIKE t2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql>
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `all_denorm`.`process_denorm` $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `all_denorm`.`process_denorm` ()
    -> BEGIN
    ->
    ->     DECLARE given_id,current_id,last_id,processing INT;
    ->     DECLARE delimiter_char CHAR(1);
    ->
    ->     SET current_id = 0;
    ->     SET processing = 1;
    ->     SET delimiter_char = '|';
    ->     WHILE processing = 1 DO
    ->         SELECT MIN(id) INTO given_id FROM t1 WHERE id > current_id;
    ->         IF ISNULL(given_id) THEN
    ->             SET processing = 0;
    ->         ELSE
    ->             SET current_id = given_id;
    ->             SELECT
    ->                 REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('(''',REPLACE(txt,delimiter_char,'''),('''),''')'),'(','(QQQ,'),'QQQ',FLOOR(given_id))
    ->                 INTO @insert_list FROM t1 WHERE id = given_id;
    ->             SELECT CONCAT('insert into t2 (parent_id,value) values ',@insert_list) INTO @insert_SQL;
    ->             PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_SQL;
    ->             EXECUTE stmt;
    ->             DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    ->         END IF;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->
    ->     SET current_id = 0;
    ->     SET processing = 1;
    ->     SET delimiter_char = ',';
    ->     WHILE processing = 1 DO
    ->         SELECT MIN(id) INTO given_id FROM t2 WHERE id > current_id;
    ->         IF ISNULL(given_id) THEN
    ->             SET processing = 0;
    ->         ELSE
    ->             SET current_id = given_id;
    ->             SELECT
    ->                 REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('(''',REPLACE(value,delimiter_char,'''),('''),''')'),'(','(QQQ,'),'QQQ',FLOOR(given_id))
    ->                 INTO @insert_list FROM t2 WHERE id = given_id;
    ->             SELECT CONCAT('insert into t3 (parent_id,value) values ',@insert_list) INTO @insert_SQL;
    ->             PREPARE stmt FROM @insert_SQL;
    ->             EXECUTE stmt;
    ->             DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    ->         END IF;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->
    ->     SELECT * FROM t1;
    ->     SELECT * FROM t2;
    ->     SELECT * FROM t3;
    ->
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> CALL process_denorm();
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | txt                                                 |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 23 | first,second|third,fourth,fifth|sixth               |
| 24 | seventh,eighth|ninth|tenth,eleven|twelfth           |
| 25 | thirteenth|fourteenth|fifteenth|sixteen|seventeenth |
| 26 | eighteenth,nineteenth|twentieth                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| id | parent_id | VALUE                 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1 |        23 | first,second          |
|  2 |        23 | third,fourth,fifth    |
|  3 |        23 | sixth                 |
|  4 |        24 | seventh,eighth        |
|  5 |        24 | ninth                 |
|  6 |        24 | tenth,eleven          |
|  7 |        24 | twelfth               |
|  8 |        25 | thirteenth            |
|  9 |        25 | fourteenth            |
| 10 |        25 | fifteenth             |
| 11 |        25 | sixteen               |
| 12 |        25 | seventeenth           |
| 13 |        26 | eighteenth,nineteenth |
| 14 |        26 | twentieth             |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
14 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | parent_id | VALUE       |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |         1 | first       |
|  2 |         1 | second      |
|  3 |         2 | third       |
|  4 |         2 | fourth      |
|  5 |         2 | fifth       |
|  6 |         3 | sixth       |
|  7 |         4 | seventh     |
|  8 |         4 | eighth      |
|  9 |         5 | ninth       |
| 10 |         6 | tenth       |
| 11 |         6 | eleven      |
| 12 |         7 | twelfth     |
| 13 |         8 | thirteenth  |
| 14 |         9 | fourteenth  |
| 15 |        10 | fifteenth   |
| 16 |        11 | sixteen     |
| 17 |        12 | seventeenth |
| 18 |        13 | eighteenth  |
| 19 |        13 | nineteenth  |
| 20 |        14 | twentieth   |
+----+-----------+-------------+
20 rows in set (0.04 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!